# How to send a SPARQL cURL request based on a query file?

Tags: curl, sparql

I have a SPARQL query in a file called `test.rq`.  What is a good way of sending a SPARQL request with cURL that uses the query from that file?

(I'm able to perform such a request with a dedicated SPARQL client or by programming the request by using an HTTP library, but I'm assuming quick command-line request, e.g., with cURL should be doable as well.)

There are three standardized ways for sending a SPARQL request:

#### Attempt 1: `GET`

I tried something like the following, but `$(VALUE)` must come from the file `test.rq` and it must be URL-encoded.

```
curl -d 'query=$(VALUE)' $(ENDPOINT)
```

#### Approach 2: URL-encoded `POST`

I tried something like the following, but `$(VALUE)` should -- again -- come from file `test.rq`, and URL-encoding should be applied.

```
curl -X POST -d '$(VALUE)' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' $(ENDPOINT)
```

#### Approach 3: Direct `POST`

This should have worked without URL encoding, doing something like the following.

```
curl -X POST -d '@query.rq' -H 'Content-Type: application/sparql-query' $(ENDPOINT)
```

Unfortunately, most SPARQL endpoints do not support this third approach :(

Comment: Does nothing work for you? What about simply using `curl --form "query=@query.rq" $(ENDPOINT)`

Comment: I'm surprised using "application/sparql-query" does not work because I understood it to be a common way to send large queries.

Comment: Case 1 from a file: Use `curl --data-urlencode 'query@Q.rq' $(ENDPOINT)`

Comment: @AndyS In my experience, direct POST does not work on any Virtuoso endpoint (and there are many of them).  Direct POST is also not supported on two GraphDB endpoints I'm using, but I don't know whether that is due to configuration.

Comment: @AndyS or AKSW Can you post your cURL line as a solution?  Preferably also with a cURL line for the URL-encoded POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 from a file:

URL encode the contents of the file and put it in the HTTP URL query string as `?query=`

`curl --data-urlencode 'query@Q.rq' $(ENDPOINT)`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, which approach is supported depends on the triple store. [Approach 1 url-encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46727873/4469267) works eg. with Virtuoso, Approach 3 works eg. with Blazegraph.